# Generating a list of pure variables

Tags: functions, pure-function, palindrome

I want to pass a list of pure variables to a function, in which the ordering of the variables matters. For instance, if I want a palindrome, my function might be:

```
func[{#1,#2,#2,#1}&]
```

I want to be able to generalise this to an arbitrary number of variables:

```
func[{#1,...,#n,...,#1}&]
```

So what I want is a simple way to write a function g[n] that calls func with n variables. How to achieve this? I've tried generating the list {#1,...,#n,...,#1}& with a Table, but it seems Mathematica is not interpreting the ampersand correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Witness the following:

```
With[{n = 7}, 
     Function[Evaluate[ArrayPad[Slot /@ Range[n], {0, n - 1}, "Reflected"]]]]
       {#1, #2, #3, #4, #5, #6, #7, #6, #5, #4, #3, #2, #1} &

With[{n = 7}, 
     Function[Evaluate[ArrayPad[Slot /@ Range[n], {0, n}, "Reversed"]]]]
       {#1, #2, #3, #4, #5, #6, #7, #7, #6, #5, #4, #3, #2, #1} &
```

Answer (score 8):

How about this:

```
g[n_]:=Function @@ {Slot /@ Join[#, Reverse[#]]&@Range[n]}
```

For a random order:

```
gr[n_] := Function @@ {Slot/@Array[RandomInteger[{1, n}] &, 2 n]}
```

All in all you can replace `Range[n]` with your own order of integers depending what you want to accomplice.

Answer (score 3):

A variation on J.M.'s approach using [`PadRight`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadRight.html):

```
f1 = Function @@ {PadRight[Slot /@ Range[#], 2 # - 1 , "Reflected"]} &;

f1 @ 7
```

> ```
> {#1, #2, #3, #4, #5, #6, #7, #6, #5, #4, #3, #2, #1} &
> ```

And using the four-argument form of [`Array`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html):

```
f2 = Array[Slot, #, 1, Function @@ {{##, ##2 & @@ Reverse @ {##}}} &] &;

f2 @ 7
```

> ```
> {#1, #2, #3, #4, #5, #6, #7, #6, #5, #4, #3, #2, #1} &
> ```

```
f3 = Function @@ Array[Slot, #, 1, {PadRight[{##}, 2 Length@{##} - 1 , "Reflected"]}&]&;

f3 @ 7
```

> ```
> {#1, #2, #3, #4, #5, #6, #7, #6, #5, #4, #3, #2, #1} &
> ```